# Cannot Import Material UI In React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui

I have installed @material-ui/icons using npm but anytime i run an import for

## PS: I have Installed @material-ui/icons

> import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';

I get the following error

```
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/@material-ui/icons/utils/createSvgIcon.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon' in '/home/freduah/react-amazon-clone/node_modules/@material-ui/icons/utils'
```

Comment: Have you installed `@material-ui/core` as well ? The icon library requires `<SvgIcon>` from `@material-ui/core` as well as stated [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons#installation).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Material Icons?

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/icons

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/icons
```

Check following page.
https://material-ui.com/components/icons/

Answer (score 0):

As far I know you should have installed `Material-UI` itself. Because icons using `SvgIcon` components from the core package.

https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/:

> converted to SvgIcon components.

How to install the core package:
https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core`
```